# combination of artwork size and resolution exceeds the maximum that can be rasterized

Tags: adobe-illustrator

'combination of artwork size and resolution exceeds the maximum that can be rasterised'

I had this message pop up now my whole document has warped -

is there anyway to recover this to it's original state?

[image]

Comment: What does "whole document has warped" mean??

Comment: What size are you trying to export the image?  And why do you need to rasterize it?  Did you not save the AI file?

Comment: Not trying to export - this happened when I opened the document up - and by warped the vector strokes have changed causing these lines, however each time the file is opened it's lines appear differently

Comment: "Causing these lines" -- What lines? Realize no one here knows what the art is *supposed* to look like.

Answer (score -1):

Illustrator is 32 bit only and has a limit of 3GB or RAM usage, it is more a limitation than a bug.

It has a limit to the size of a tiff I can export for instance and you may have reached that limit.

Try opening it in Photoshop before starting all over and then save it either as a psd or tiff.

Comment: Illustrator is 64-bit

Comment: 64-bit support means that Illustrator can leverage more than 3 GB of RAM, which can double its speed. Applying effects to large files or working on multiple files becomes a lot more efficient. 

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/atv/cs6-tutorials/understanding-64-bit-support.html

Comment: Has been 64 Bit since CS6